# Use spacy.explain() on a list of tags

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, spacy

I would like to see what these list of tags mean using spacy.explain(), however it returns None when i try to iterate over the list.

```
dep_list= ['nk', 'sb', 'svp', 'mo']

for x in dep_list:
    print(spacy.explain('x'))
```

my desired output:

```
'noun kernel element'
'subject'
'separable verb prefix'
'modifier'
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you have a typo:

```
print(spacy.explain('x'))
```

should be

```
print(spacy.explain(x))
```

and then you'd get:

```
noun kernel element
subject
separable verb prefix
modifier
```

Comment: oh, right. thank you for pointing that out